# In which table Order's comments history information will store?

Tags: paypal, sales-order

I'm using paypal express checkout.and In order comments history tab the following type of information is stored.

Payflow PNREF: #B1PP7A1A6D7C. Authorized amount of $94.99. Transaction ID: "28N891255K2125216". 
I want to know above information in which table field contain?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table is `sales_flat_order_status_history`.
But if that is a response from a payment gateway it might be located in `sales_flat_order_payment`.
Check both to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

In magento 2.3 community version, it is present in the table named "sales_order_status_history.In that table column named "comment" will have this values.